# Adding click listeners onto code generated in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a Javascript/jQuery slider class which builds a slideshow on a page when invoked.

Here is my Cycler object code:

```
//Cycle
var Cycler = function(options) {
    this.cycleElement = options.cycleElement;
    this.speed = options.speed || 5000;
    this.effect = options.effect || "linear";
    this.currentItem = null;    
    this.children = this.addItemsToCycler();
    this.buttons = null;
    if(options.buttonsEl.length != "") {
        this.buttons = this.generateButtons();
    }       

}

Cycler.prototype.addItemsToCycler = function() {
    var children = [];
    jQuery(this.cycleElement + " > div.cycle-object").each(function(item, value) {
        children.push(value);
    });
    return children;
}

Cycler.prototype.generateButtons = function() {
    var buttons = "<ul>";
    var counter = 0;
    this.children.forEach(function(item) {          
        buttons += "<li><a href='#' data-rel='" + counter + "'></a></li>";
        counter++;
    });
    buttons += "</ul>";
    jQuery("#cycle-buttons").html(buttons);
}

Cycler.prototype.showItem = function() {
    jQuery(this.children).fadeOut("slow");
    jQuery(this.children[this.currentItem]).fadeIn("slow");         
}

Cycler.prototype.start = function() {
    if(this.currentItem == null || this.children.length <= this.currentItem) {          
        this.currentItem = 0;
    }
    this.showItem();

    var self = this;
    interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        self.next();
    }, this.speed);
}

Cycler.prototype.next = function() {
    if(this.currentItem >= (this.children.length - 1)) {
        this.currentItem = 0;
    } else {
        this.currentItem++;
    }
    this.showItem();
}

Cycler.prototype.prev = function() {
    if(this.currentItem <= 0) {
        this.currentItem = this.children.length - 1;
    } else {
        this.currentItem--;
    }
    this.showItem();
}

Cycler.prototype.pause = function() {
    if(this.interval == null) {
        console.log("Cycler is already paused");
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = null;
    }
}

Cycler.prototype.gotoItem = function(gotoItem) {
    this.currentItem = gotoItem;
    this.showItem();
}
```

The markup:

```
<div id="cycle-wrap">
        <div id="background-cycle">
            <div data-rel="0" class="cycle-object"></div>
            <div data-rel="1" class="cycle-object"></div>
            <div data-rel="2" class="cycle-object"></div>               
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <div id="cycle-buttons">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my client code which creates an instance of the class:

```
//Cycler
    var cycler = new Cycler({
        cycleElement : "#background-cycle",
        speed   : 5000,
        effect  : "linear",
        buttonsEl : "#cycle-buttons"
    });

    cycler.start();
```

Now, if a user supplies an element in the 'buttonsEl' variable which is passed to the class, I want the class to generate a list of li elements which when clicked will take the user to that slide. I have done this via the 'generateButtons' function I have already created the prototype function for this called 'goToItem' as you can see above. I am linking the li elements and the corresponding html using a 'data'rel' attribute.

What I would like to do is add click listeners onto each list element (that is generated in the 'generateButtons' function) which will pass the data-rel attribute through to my 'goToItem' function. Does anyone know of the best way this would be incorporated into my code, keeping it nice and OOP.
Thanks

Comment: You can use [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event handlers to elements, also newly generated ones. This is probably relevant: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements . Or use event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Cycler` constructor we could pass the `buttonsEl` to the `generateButtons`. Then this method will be able to insert the buttons in the desired element.

```
// Not sure if you want this comparison. If works by coercion but it's tricky. And it
// will fail if your client doesn't pass a buttonsEl option.
// I would prefer something like this:
// if(options.buttonsEl && options.buttonsEl.length > 0) {
if(options.buttonsEl.length != "") {
    this.buttons = this.generateButtons(options.buttonsEl);
}
```

The `generateButtons` could be something like this:

```
Cycler.prototype.generateButtons = function(buttonsEl) {
    var $buttons = jQuery("<ul></ul>");
    this.children.forEach(function(item, counter) {          
        $buttons.append("<li><a href='#' data-rel='" + counter + "'></a></li>");
    });
    // Capture cycler this to be able to invoke the gotoItem method
    // within the event handler
    var that = this;
    $buttons.on('click', 'li', function () {
        that.gotoItem($(this).find('a').data('rel'));
    });
    jQuery(buttonsEl).html($buttons);

    return $buttons;
}
```